# Is the net/http gem not in the default library for Ruby?

Tags: ruby, rubygems, net-http

I want to create a Gemfile.lock by typing 'bundle install' but my local machine can't find the gem net/http. I've tried typing 'bundle update net/http' & 'bundle --full-index' & 'gem install bundler' but I keep getting this error when I try 'bundle install' again:

> Could not find gem 'net/http' in rubygems repository https://rubygems.org/ or installed locally. The source does not contain any versions of 'net/http'

my Gemfile resembles the following:

```
source "https://rubygems.org"

gem 'open-uri'
gem 'nokogiri'
gem 'net/http'
gem 'pry'
```

Other solutions to this problem suggest removing the line for gem net/http because net/http is part of the default library for Ruby...however when I do this everything loads fine, and I can create a Gemfile.lock upon typing 'bundle install' but when I run my code I get the following error:

> Traceback (most recent call last):
> run.rb:4:in `': uninitialized constant Net (NameError)
> Did you mean?  Set

The line of code this refers to is

```
response = Net::HTTP.get(url)
```

I'm running Ruby version 2.6.1

Comment: Did you `require 'net/http'`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The name of the gem is [net-http](https://rubygems.org/gems/net-http). It is one of the first hits when you google for "net/http".

However, in Ruby 2.6.1, [net/http is still part of the standard library](https://ruby-doc.org/stdlib-2.6.1/libdoc/net/http/rdoc/), not a gem. Net/http was only removed from the standard library in Ruby 3.0.

Answer (score 0):

There are two different kinds of standard gems:

- Default gems: These gems are part of Ruby and you can always require them directly. You cannot remove them. They are maintained by Ruby core.
- Bundled gems: The behavior of bundled gems is similar to normal gems, but they get automatically installed when you install Ruby. They can be uninstalled and they are maintained outside of Ruby core.

Your problem is the wrong name gem ('net-http' instead of 'net/http', you can run `gem search ^net` to find out remote gems start by 'net').

If the gem is 'default', no need to declare it in Gemfile.

You can check standard default gems on: https://stdgems.org/